# bower_components to public folder - meanjs app

Tags: bower, meanjs

In the root folder of my meanjs app I have a `bower_components` folder. Within this folder are all the required front libs for my meanjs app.

I would like to add another lib. So I installed it with `bower install pathfinding`.

The folder gets added to `bower_components` and I updated the `bower.json` file, and did a `bower install`

Apparantely I'm not allowed to include files from the `bower_components` folder to my `/config/assets/default.js` file.

How do I correctly add pathfinding folder to my `public/lib` folder without copy + pasting from my `bower_components` folder?